# how to find registry Domain ID if we have signing apks

Tags: security, spring-security, firebase-cloud-messaging, devsecops

I got my answer for signing apks on  june 4 '13 at 3 am. how to find
Registry Domain ID.
what are steps requre to find Registry Domain ID. what are steps required.

how to solve this type of problem when we have only signing apps file and date and time mention